# How To Fix Theme Switching Error Message In 2.2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.4

On applying any new theme getting an error in the admin panel.`something went wrong while saving this configuration. Area is already set`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in this file.

> Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate.php

```
public function setForcedArea($templateId)
{
    if ($this->area) {
        throw new \LogicException(__('Area is already set'));
    }
    $this->area = $this->emailConfig->getTemplateArea($templateId);
    return $this;
}
```

**To:**

```
public function setForcedArea($templateId)
{
    if (!isset($this->area)) {
        $this->area = $this->emailConfig->getTemplateArea($templateId);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

It will fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution:

Edit inside this file path:

> vendor/magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php

Replace this code:

```
public function setForcedArea($templateId)
{
if ($this->area) {
throw new \LogicException(__('Area is already set'));
}
$this->area = $this->emailConfig->getTemplateArea($templateId);
return $this;
```

Replace With:

```
    public function setForcedArea($templateId)
{
if (!isset($this->area)) {
$this->area = $this->emailConfig->getTemplateArea($templateId);
}
return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is known issue in **Magento 2.2.4**.

You can check below link to resolve your issue.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14968

Go through it and change code as workaround.

If you are connected to git than you can pull from git to make your Magento installtion updated.

Answer (score 0):

This is known issue of Magento 2.2.4
I have solved this issue by updating the following file:

> Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate

```
public function setForcedArea($templateId)
{
    if (!isset($this->area)) {
        $this->area = $this->emailConfig->getTemplateArea($templateId);
    }
    return $this;
}
```